# Using @import on less with a variable param

Tags: less

I am doing a *mixin* in *less*.

For example:

```
.change-theme(@theme) {
    // Load core variables and mixins
    @import "@{theme}/variables";
    @import "@{theme}/mixin";
}

.theme-black {
    .change-theme("black");
}
```

But i am having this error:

> { [Error: variable @theme is undefined in file theme.less line no. 8]
>     type: 'Syntax',
>     filename: ' theme.less',
>     index: 140,
>     line: 8,
>     callLine: NaN,
>     callExtract: undefined,
>     column: 2,
>     extract: [ '.theme-black {', '  .change-theme("black");', '}' ],
>     message: 'variable @theme is undefined in file theme.less line no. 8',
>     stack: undefined,
>     lineNumber: 8,
>     fileName: 'theme.less',
>     name: 'Error',
>     showStack: false,
>     showProperties: true,
>     plugin: 'gulp-less',
>     __safety: { toString: [Function] } }

Comment: See [Variable Interpolation: Import statements](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-import-statements). I.e. `@import "@{theme}";`.

Comment: Thanks, now it works, but i have another error, i updated my question.

Comment: Variable interpolation for imports inside mixins requires Less `v2.0.0` or higher to work properly (in earlier versions it was considered unsafe since the imported file can redefine the interpolated variable thus casting for ghosts). I don't know though if `gulp-less` itself can interfere there not quite supporting it too... Do you use an up-to-date `gulp-less` version?